# socket.io unity authentication

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I have this use case:
- I'm working on a game with a webapp for user management and chat, which is on MERN, and a unity game, with socket.io as the real time messaging layer for the multiplayer game. 
- User may register to webapp by either providing a pair of email/password, or getting authenticated on FB/Gamil/etc. as usual, in which case the user's email is obtained and saved to MongoDB and this is done by passport.
- There is no session in express side, and socket.io is on a redis. There is no cookie but JWT is used.

My problem is that I don't know what's the best practices in this. I read this 
[article](http://www.codedevlog.com/blog/2014/10/23/socket-dot-io-user-sessions-with-redis-and-json-web-tokens/)
and this 
[one](https://www.codementor.io/tips/0217388244/sharing-passport-js-sessions-with-both-express-and-socket-io)
which both have content and code close to what I want to do, but in the first one:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
```

while I don't want to use cookie at all, and the other one also has in code:

```
cookie: {
secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'development' && process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'test',maxAge: 2419200000}...
```

Also, I found this on 
[github](https://github.com/cmorsucci/socketio-jwt-unity)

which suggests for the client side (unity):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
socket.on('authenticated', function () {
  //do other things
})
.emit('authenticate', {token: jwt}); //send the jwt
```

});

meaning that:
1. socket is created
2. authentication is requested

but I think that the approach I found in the other article is better, where the socket is not created at all if the JWT for auth is not provided at the first ever connection request sent to "io", so if I'd do it I'd issue:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {query: {"JWT":"myjwt"}});
```

and in my server side where I have:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){...});
```

I'd like to first get the JWT:

```
var jwt = socket.handshake.query["JWT"];
```

and then if auth will be unsuccessful, simply return socket.disconnect('reason') and do not open any connection at all (here maybe I just didn't understand, say, that the approach the Author took in the github source is using a middle ware technique and it is maybe also done before anything else).

I still could not find out what is the best practice that Gurus use, please help me get clear.